# Как найти время исполнения в наихудшем случае, используя О-большое?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сложность

> Какое значение выведет следующая функция?
> Ответ должен быть в форме функции числа n.
> Найдите время исполнения в наихудшем случае, используя О-большое.
>
> Функция на python:
>
> ```
> def F(n):
>     r = 0
>     for i in range(1, n + 1):
>         for j in range(i + 1, n + 1):
>             for k in range(i + j - 1, n + 1):
>                 r += 1
>     return r
> ```

Я пытался выразить это всё через Σ, однако в некоторых случаях i - j + 1 может быть больше, чем n, из-за этого всё моё решение рушится. У меня была идея в таком случае записать выражение Σᵢ₌₁ⁿ Σⱼ₌ᵢ₊₁ⁿ ((n - i - j + 2) / 2 + |n - i - j + 2| / 2), что брало бы максимум между нулём и n - i - j + 2, однако я не представляю как работать с этим модулем в сумме.

Вот что у меня получилось в первом решении без учёта того, что n - i - j + 2 может быть < 0, если это вдруг как-то поможет: r = (n^2 - n) / 2

Comment: На все ваши прошлые вопросы есть ответы, а вот принято совсем мало. Зря.

Comment: `O` тут в итоге всё-равно будет `O(n^3)` мне кажется, так то вообще.

Comment: @CrazyElf , в реальности чуть меньше, тк на каждом for элементов меньше становится из за i и j, но тк константу при О опускают, то по идее вы правы и О(n^3)

Comment: вот статья, может помочь -> https://proglib.io/p/slozhnost-algoritmov-i-operaciy-na-primere-python-2020-11-03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимательно посмотрим на то, что у нас записано в параметрах цикла и подумаем, как это всё можно привести к одной формуле. Для каждого *i от 1 до n* есть свой *j = i + 1 от i + 1 до n*, а для каждого *j = i + 1 от i + 1 до n* создаётся *k = i + j - 1 от i + j - 1 до n*. *i + 1* и *i + j - 1* может быть больше *n*, тогда цикл не проитерируется.

Чтобы понять, какую формулу тут можно подобрать, построим таблицу Кэли для *i* и *j* с операцией *i * j = i + j - 1* на примере *n = 5*:

[image: Таблица Кэлли для n = 5]

*j = i + 1*, поэтому оно начинается минимум с двойки. Также исключаем все случаи, когда i <= j.

Все получившиеся числа больше *n = 5* мы вычёркиваем, так как в этом случае итерации по циклу не будет. У нас остаётся меньше половины таблицы со значениями <= 5.

[image: Сколько раз итерируется цикл]

Для каждого начального значения *j*, например, *j = 2*, далее цикл проходит до значения *n = 5*, потом *j* увеличивается на *1* и проходит от *j = 3* до *n = 5* (см. на зелёные стрелочки). После того, как первый столбец был полностью пройден, мы переходим ко второму, при этом, столбец становится короче на 1 значение сверху и снизу, в остальном по столбцу происходит такой же подсчёт, как и на предыдущем.

Теперь выведем формулу: Σ ( ((n - 2·i)·(n - 2·i - 1)) / 2, i = 0 to ⌊n / 2⌋ - 1)

Проверим её:

F(5) = 13, (5 * 4 + 3 * 2) / 2 = 13.

F(6) = 22, (6 * 5 + 4 * 3 + 2 * 1) / 2 = 22.

Всё, осталось только привести её к формуле без Σ. Здесь я не буду писать все вычисления, по ответ такой:

F(n) = ((n^2 - n)·⌊n/2⌋ + 2/3 · ⌊n/2⌋·(⌊n/2⌋ - 1)·(2·⌊n/2⌋ - 1) + (⌊n/2⌋ - 1)·⌊n/2⌋ - 2·n·(⌊n/2⌋ - 1)·⌊n/2⌋) / 2

Я проверял её для *n* от 1 до 500, всё сошлось.

Асимптотика тут примерно F(n) = O(n^3), т.к. в итоговой формуле при раскрытии скобок будет присутствовать член ⌊n/2⌋^3.

Comment: Значит, я таки правильно прикинул )

Comment: @CrazyElf Ага, но когда я решал эту задачу, у меня часто в ответе получалось O(n^2), поэтому я даже сомневаться начал)